# What is the best directory to use for my C program?

Tags: bash, directory, binary

### The problem?

I'm currently in the middle of building a simple shell, and I'm confused on where to install it to in a production environment.

### What I've tried

I've thought to put it in the following directories:

- `/usr/local/`
- `/etc/`

### Background Info

- Written in C + Bash
- Compile from source only (nothing is prebuilt)
- Installs via `git` + `gcc`
- Supports multiple Linux platforms -- Ubuntu, CentOS

Answer (score 1):

If every user needs access to it, use `/usr/bin`.

If it's needed for boot (default shell, for instance) or for single user mode to repair a system, then you should consider `/bin`.

Use `man hier` for a description of each directory and what it's meant to be used for.

Also, consider going through the [Ubuntu packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) for better integration.

Comment: If the program were installed by a local user without elevated privileges, what would be the next best option?

Comment: @NerdOfCode Anywhere you like within your home directory, then. Some suggest `/home/user/local/` while others prefer `/home/user/bin/` - Then you edit the path so you can execute from anywhere if you prefer.